# how to make div s re size with fixed position with according to browser size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Am doing with small bootstrap application. 
Here there are two  divs side by side. First div is with bootstrap table and second with image.

My doubt is if i re size browser, how i can make their position fix but with re size.

Here is my sample code.

[`link`](http://jsfiddle.net/ga11Lj2r/)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, and your example doesn't include bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more detailed. But I think I got an idea of what you're trying to do...

You will have to use the jquery resize event on the browser. Basically a function that is called every time the browser size is changed.

`$(window).resize(function(){ /* BROWSER RESIZED. TO STUFF */ });`

Then in that function you have the get the browser's current width or height. And use that to resize or reposition your divs.

Here is an example that keep 2 different divs side by side on a page. You can do this easily with just CSS, but this is just to give you an idea.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  
  //Get browser width & height
  var browserWidth = $(window).width();
  var browserHeight = $(window).height();
  
  //Some computations for example
  var divWidth = browserWidth/2;
  
  //Change Div's width
  $("div1").css("width", divWidth+"px");
  $("div2").css("width", divWidth+"px");
  //Reposition Div 2
  $("div2").css("left", "50%");
  
});
```